# Is it illegal in any state in the USA to enter a restroom whose sign is not one's sex?

Tags: united-states

As a trans person in the USA, I'm very worried about this. When I'm halfway through transition, will I be arrested for using either restroom?

Comment: Presumably you know of North Carolina's law. At the state level and AFAICT, Ohio, Washington and New York have no laws that address the question of sex and bathrooms one way or the other. Cleveland for example had an ordinances that allowed facility owners to set their own policy. My suspicion is that there are no general laws that directly address the matter, but a proprietor could tell you to leave and the police could enforce such a request, under the rubric trespass.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is illegal in **North Carolina**, which defines your sex as what's on your birth certificate.  At any point in your transition, even when it's long complete, you'll still have to use the restroom for the gender on your birth certificate (hypothetically assuming the law is still in place).  See e.g. [this CNN coverage](http://www.cnn.com/2016/03/23/politics/north-carolina-gender-bathrooms-bill/) and [this followup](http://www.cnn.com/2016/03/29/health/north-carolina-bathroom-law-cards/).

Will you actually be arrested?  Probably only if there's a complaint. [The police haven't yet figured out how they're supposed to enforce this law](http://www.motherjones.com/politics/2016/04/north-carolina-lgbt-bathrooms-hb2-enforcement).

Comment: In government facilities, not in general.

Comment: @user6726 In general, including at privately owned but publicly accessible businesses.

Comment: i may have missed that. Can you point to the section?

Comment: The explicitly stated intent is for application to "all businesses, organizations, and employers doing business in the State."  "Places of public accommodation" is defined in §143-422.12, by reference to G.S. 168A-3(8). See also §143-760(b) which does not limit "**every** multiple occupancy bathroom or changing facility" to only those located in government facilities. Finally, just check out the news coverage and expert interpretations by others.

Comment: IMO a rather idiotic law. If my company employs two transgender person, one male looking female-to-male transgender and one female looking male-to-female transgender, this forces them both to go (a) where they don't want to go and (b) where the stand out and attract bad attention and possibly danger to themselves.

Comment: Plus the obvious risk that if I need a bathroom and have to pick the right one, if I say a female looking person entering one door I might (as a man) automatically pick the other door and get it completely wrong because of this stupid law.

Comment: @gnasher729 there are a lot of folks who agree with you for the same and other reasons.  This law will be at issue in the upcoming gubernatorial election, so things may change after that.

Comment: Is it possible to change the sex on your birth certificate? Also, would your sex on a passport override that? I know you can change that as poart of the transition.

Comment: The law specifically refers to birth certificate, so as long as this law is in place your passport would not override that. The law was hastily written and pushed through in a special session. It has lots of different issues; I wouldn't bet that the law will still exist in precisely its current form a year from now. A lot of folks are choosing to avoid public bathrooms in NC, or avoid the state in general, for now. Changing your birth certificate depends on where you were born; you have to inquire with the authority who issues birth certificates there. It *is* possible in at least some places.

Comment: The law in question has since been repealed.